# cannot git push to aws: fatal No path specified

Tags: git, amazon-web-services

I was able to push my changes to AWS with no problem last week, but my computer crashed and I had to set it all up again. Now, pushing to Github works without any problems, but pushing to my EC2 instance (ubuntu) gives this message:
fatal: No path specified. See 'man git-pull' for valid url syntax
I've tried all kinds of different syntax and am having no luck. I believe this is the correct one though:

git remote set-url aws ssh://ubuntu@52.10.18.15/home/ubuntu/jade.git/

Does anyone have any ideas on this? I can't find any info online to solve this problem! Grateful for any assistance!

Answer (score 1):

According to github manual the command looks like

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USERNAME/OTHERREPOSITORY.git
```

Please note there is no ssh:// in front like for https and no trailing slash at **jade.git/**

I believe you have to run command

```
git remote set-url aws git@52.10.18.15:ubuntu/jade.git
```

or maybe

```
git remote set-url aws git@52.10.18.15:jade/jade.git
```

or even

```
git remote set-url aws ubuntu@52.10.18.15:ubuntu/jade.git
```

It depends on how git was configured on EC2

Make sure you have git user on EC2

And then **git push aws master**

Comment: Thank you for your help! Somehow it worked after I removed it and added it again. This is how it looks now:
aws ssh://ubuntu@52.10.18.15/home/ubuntu/jade.git
I think maybe the trailing slash did it!